# Is there a way to know which compiler generated a static library?

Tags: linker, build-process, solaris

A third party provided me a static lib (.a) to link with on solaris station.
I tried to compile with sunpro, and failed at link step.

I suppose the issue is coming from the compiler I use (gcc instead?) or simply its version (as the std lib provided by the compiler could change from the version expected by the library AFAIK it could leads to errors at link step).

How could I know which compiler was used to generate this lib? Is there some tools doing that? Some option in sunpro/gcc or whatever?

***As an hint:*** I've read some time ago that compilers use different mangling conventions when generating object files (true?). Still, **"nm --demangle"** command line prints me well all function names from debug symbols in this static lib. How does it work ? If my assumption is ok, **nm** does have a way to resolve which convention is in use in a static library, isn't it? Or is it simply meaning that lib was generated by GNU gcc, as nm is a part of GNU binutils?

I am not close to my workstation so I can't copy & paste error output from the linker (not for the moment but I could copy them in a further edit)

Comment: Why don't you ask the "third party" who supplied the library for instructions on how to use it?

Comment: I asked them. But no answer from their support team, which is reluctant to ask the dev team, it seems... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use the `strings` program (with the '`-a`' option, or my own variant where the '`-a`' behaviour is standard) and look for the tell-tale signs.  For example, in one of my own libraries, I find:

```
/work1/gcc/v4.2.3/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.3/include
/work1/gcc/v4.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.3.0/include
/work1/gcc/v4.3.1/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.3.1/include
/work1/gcc/v4.3.3/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.3.3/include
```

That suggests that the code in the library has been compiled with a variety of versions of GCC over a period of years (actually, I'm quite startled to find so many versions in a single library).

Another library contains:

```
cg: Sun Compiler Common 11 Patch 120760-06 2006/05/26
acomp: Sun C 5.8 Patch 121015-02 2006/03/29
iropt: Sun Compiler Common 11 Patch 120760-06 2006/05/26
/compilers/v11/SUNWspro/prod/bin/cc -O -v -Xa -xarch=v9 ...
```

So, there are usually fingerprints in the object files indicating which compiler was used.  But you have to know how to look for them.

Comment: I am trying to find ways to extract the compiler version from clang compiled mac object files and static libraries. I was able to extract the compiler version from 4 out of 40 object files in the library by string dumping using strings command and grepping for "clang" which displayed "Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)" but other files did not have this string.

On using mach-o-view tool to look inside the sections, the object file from which the compiler version was extracted had a Section64(__DWARF,__debug_str) which had the string "Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)"

Comment: Did you use `strings -a` or just `strings`?  The `-a` is important, usually.  I tend to use a home-built GCC (currently 9.2.0) on my MacBook Pros — one runs macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (work; grumble!) and the other macOS Catalina 10.15.3.  I just recompiled a small library (9 source files) with clang 11.0.0 (Xcode 11.3.1), and the system `strings` reported 9 occurrences of Apple (`/usr/bin/strings libdiag.a | grep -i apple | sort | uniq -c` yielded `9 Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)`.  I'm not sure if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jonathan.
I tried using strings and strings -a. Both did not find it.
I am able to reproduce the same in few files. But in few object files, the string is missing. Do you know of any compiler flags or somethings that will strip this out?

Comment: I'm not aware of an option to strip this metadata out of object files — I never bother.  The `otool` command can list all sorts of information — that seems to be `llvm-otool` according to `man otool`, and is a cover for `llvm-objdump`.  Classically, the `strip` command removes unnecessary material from object files – it has many options on macOS.  I'm not sure what other commands might be of relevance.

Comment: Jonathan, here I have posted a simple hello world cpp which I converted to object file using clang++ -c. But, strings -a does not display the "clang-<version>". Why?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676912/how-to-identify-the-xcode-version-and-compiler-version-used-to-build-an-artifact

Comment: `<iostream.h>`?  That's so nearly prehistoric it is … unexpected.  Maybe it won't embed a version because it is ashamed to admit it compiled the code with that header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207634/discussion-between-electronic-coder-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: When I change `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>` and produce an object file, I can find `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/` and `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)` in the output with just `/usr/bin/strings` (no `-a` option).  That may not clearly indicate C++, but the other symbols surely do.

Answer (score 6):

Extract the object files from the archive then run the `strings` command on some of them (first on the smaller ones since there'd be less noise to sift through). Many compilers insert ASCII signatures in the object files.

For example, the following meaningless source file, `foo.c`:

```
extern void blah();
```

when compiled on my Fedora 10 machine into foo.o via `gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c` results in a 647 byte `foo.o` object file. Running `strings` on `foo.o` results in

```
GCC: (GNU) 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7)
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.text
.data
.bss
.comment
.note.GNU-stack
foo.c
```

which makes it clear the compiler was GCC. Even if I'd compiled it with `-fno-ident`, the .GNU-stack note ELF section would have still been present.

You can extract the object files using the `ar` utility, or using Midnight Commander (which integrates ar), or you can simply run `strings` on the archive (which might give you more noise and be less relevant, but would still help.)

Comment: Or just run 'strings' directly on the library - no need to extract the object files first.

Comment: Like I mentioned, there's a lot more output, *especially* in the case of C++ object files, and it's much easier to miss compiler signatures. Also, there is no requirement that all objects in an archive be from the same compiler...

Answer (score 2):

Is the library supposed to be a C or C++ library?

If it is a C library then name mangling can not be the problem, as there is none in C. It could be however in a wrong format. Unices used to have libraries in the [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) format but almost all newer versions switched to more powerful formats like [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

If it is a C++ library then name mangling can be an issue. Most compilers embed some symbols that are compiler specific into the code, so if you have a tool like nm to list the symbols you can hopefully deduce from what compiler it came.

For example g++ creates a symbol

> __gxx_personality_v0

in it's libraries

Answer (score -1):

You can try the unix utility *file*:

```
file foo.a
```

Comment: I tried but I remember it only tells me  that this file uses the ELF format for SPARC platform. Does sunpro generates ELF format, as GCC does?

Comment: The `file` tool will hardly return info about the compiler used!