# How to identify the xcode version and compiler version used to build an artifact like object file or binary built on mac?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, artifact

If we write a hello world.cpp and build using g++ in linux, doing an objdump or a strings can expose the compiler used in linux.

> [Is there a way to know which compiler generated a static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727813/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-compiler-generated-a-static-library)

I am not able to use the same in mac.
For instance, the following artifact compiled using clang++,

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main() {
  std::cout<<"Hello world";
  return 0;
}
```

running objdump -s -j .comment a.out gives this:

> a.out: file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

How to we identify the compiler version from a mac artifact?
How does the same work on windows?

Running a strings -a does not show any reference to "clang-" string.

Comment: If you build using GCC on macOS, does the generated file contain any identifiable information about the compiler then? Then the lack of identifying information is a way to identify that the file *may* have been created by Clang.

Comment: Independent of using GCC or Clang, the compiler version is not available in .comment or any other section of the artifact.

Comment: AFAICT, using the `-g` (debugging information) option includes useful information like the compiler version; omitting it means there is no useful metadata.